# Can you detect if a function is being executed by the scheduler in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, scheduler

I have a `Job` that was originally written to be run exclusively by logged in `Users`. I now have a use case where I want to be able to dispatch the `Job` from the scheduler.

The issue I have is that the original code includes some checks on the logged in `User`, which when run by the scheduler is `null`.

What I'd ideally like to do is detect at runtime whether the `Job` has been dispatched by the scheduler and if so, bypass these tests. Is this possible?

Alternatively I'm aware that there is a `user` method on the `EventCallback` class that, according to the docs, allows you to execute the callback (this is case a `Job`) as the given user - this could also provide a solution. I've tried passing in a `User` object, and an ID, but neither behaves as I'd expect (If I log `Auth::check()` from with the Jobs `handle` method I get `false`). The docs suggest that `$user` should be a `string` so it's quite possible I'm not using the method correctly but I can't find any details about how this *should* be used.

Thanks for your help!